# Using DARTs to create a time series object - and having problems with missing dates

Tags: finance

My data is a time series of stock prices.  A portfolio of 52 stocks, about 120 days of data, and a datetime stamp for each.  I convert the tidy file into a pivot to create unique dates and put the tickers for each stock in the columns and the closing prices in the rows of the pivot.

```
target_final['date'] = pd.to_datetime(target_final['date'])
```

Create the 'target_pivot' DataFrame

```
target_pivot = target_final.pivot(index='date', columns='ticker', values='c')
target_pivot.reset_index(inplace=True)  # Reset index to move 'date' from index to a regular column
target_pivot.columns.name = None  # Remove the 'ticker' label from the columns
```

Now create the TimeSeries object using the 'date' column as the time index

```
target_ts = TimeSeries.from_dataframe(
    target_pivot,
    time_col='date',  # Use 'date' as the time column
    value_cols=target_pivot.columns[1:].tolist(),  # Exclude the 'date' column from value_cols
    fill_missing_dates=False,  # Set to False as weekends and holidays are not included
    freq='B',  # This is the desired frequency of the time series (daily data)
    fillna_value=0,  # Optional: Fill any remaining NaN with 0 (or appropriate value)
    static_covariates=['static_covariate'],
    hierarchy=None
)
```

I get the following error.

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 9>()
7
8 # Now create the TimeSeries object using the 'date' column as the time index
----> 9 target_ts = TimeSeries.from_dataframe(
10     target_pivot,
11     time_col='date',  # Use 'date' as the time column

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/darts/logging.py in raise_log(exception, logger)
127     logger.error(exception_type + ": " + message)
128
--> 129     raise exception
130
131

ValueError: **Could not correctly fill missing dates** with the observed/passed frequency `freq='B'`. Not all input time stamps contained in the newly created TimeSeries. For more information about frequency aliases, read https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases

This is odd since I'e set fill_missing_dates to False.  Also, the dates are Business dates, at least financial business dates.  So I'm not sure why I'm getting an error to fill missing dates.

I have tried changing the freq and fill_missing_dates fields with multiple options.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I changed the time_col to be the index of pandas dataframe, and it worked. But then you loose the frequency:

```
data_series = TimeSeries.from_dataframe(data_custom,
                                    value_cols=['values'],
                                    )
```